# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 7 when using $.parseJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to create named Object in javascript like this: -

```
{
id: "marker_0",
tooltip: country,
src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
width: 15,
height: 24,
geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
},
{
id: "marker_1",
tooltip: country,
src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
width: 15,
height: 24,
geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
}
```

and so on. I am getting **country, latitude, longitude** values from database. Below is my code: -

```
var objFormat;
var i =0;
var mapFormat = [];
for (var country in countries_coord) {
  values = countries_coord[country];
  objFormat = '{"id:" "marker_""' + i + '","tooltip:" "' + country + '","src:" "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png","width:" "'+ 15 + '","height:" "'+ 24 + '","geoCoords:" [ "'+ values.latitude + '", "'+values.longitude + '" ]}';
  obj = $.parseJSON(objFormat);
  mapFormat.push(objFormat);
  i++;

}
```

But I am getting the error **"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in JSON at position 7"**. I think I am not creating the object in right way. Please help. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is what I have in **countries_coord** array a complete JSON: -

```
Afghanistan
:
Object
latitude
:
"33.93911"
longitude
:
"67.709953"

Australia
:
Object
latitude
:
"-25.274398"
longitude
:
"133.775136"
```

and so on I have another values in same format.

Comment: Could you add the complete JSON with the informations, it might help a little bit

Comment: In `id` the `"marker_""'` may be read as `"id:" "marker_""1", "tooltip:"`

Comment: @Nicolas I did not understand by complete JSON?

Comment: Well in your example there seams to have a few variables, we can't help you if you we don't have any example of a real JSON feed. there is a syntax in your json, we need to know what it is.

Comment: @Nicolas Please see my edited question. Thanks.

Comment: There's no need to build JSON as a string; just build and object directly.

Answer (score 6):

I miss-understood the question here is the solution

change

```
  objFormat = '{"id:" "marker_""' + i + '","tooltip:" "' + country + '","src:" "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png","width:" "'+ 15 + '","height:" "'+ 24 + '","geoCoords:" [ "'+ values.latitude + '", "'+values.longitude + '" ]}';
```

to

```
objFormat = '{"id": "marker_' + i + '",'+
             '"tooltip": ' + country + '",'+
                   //etc 
             '"geoCoords": [ '+ values.latitude + ', '+values.longitude+' ]}';
```

Notice how I use the code indenting to make it easy to see when I have error.
You had the quote after the colon.

A JSON object needs to be a single object or an array of objects so you want

```
[ 
  {
    id: "marker_0",
    tooltip: country,
    src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
    width: 15,
    height: 24,
    geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
  },
  {
    id: "marker_1",
    tooltip: country,
    src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
    width: 15,
    height: 24,
    geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
  }
]
```

or

```
{
  location_list: [
    {
      id: "marker_0",
      tooltip: country,
      src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
      width: 15,
      height: 24,
      geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
    },
    {
      id: "marker_1",
      tooltip: country,
      src: "//localhost/mapsvg/markers/pin1_red.png",
      width: 15,
      height: 24,
      geoCoords: [latitude, longitude]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you please edit my code to achieve like above Object Format as you said.

Comment: Sorry but I did not understand your answer well that's why I am asking you to edit my code as I am new to javascript Objects. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am still getting the same issue now the error is "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I in JSON at position 29". Any idea?

Comment: I can't possibly answer your question without seeing the code -- if you are using my exact code then maybe you forgot the "+" before the variable name "i" -- or you changed the name of the variable.

Comment: Why would you build JSON as a string instead of just building an object?